# android gridview cell size

Tags: android, listview, gridview, adapter

In my gridview, all the cell initially render as rectangles, but the second time it is viewed they are square.

I have to logic to make them square, but I want them square the first time they are loaded

my problem is that I don't understand why the views are initially rectangles, or any particular proportion at all!

my XML files are all set to fill parent, and I even put in a square placeholder image in an attempt to force the views to be rendered square

is there something about gridview I should know about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to extend my ImageView within the gridview cell, and `@Override` the `onMeasure` method and dynamically generate square proportions there

Answer (score 0):

1. create a custom array adapter.(java)

see ( [Showing graphical instead of strings in an imagelist with title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531991/showing-graphical-instead-of-strings-in-an-imagelist-with-title/) )

2. in custom array adpater xml file (cell) write something like this:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="50dp"
       android:layout_height="50dp" > 
       <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/iv_caarow"
         android:src="@drawable/icon"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" />
     </RelativeLayout>
   ```

android:layout_width="50dp", you can set cell size like this.